# gdb linux - segmentation fault no symbol table found

Tags: linux, gdb

I am debugging a core dump with gdb using the binary and the core file on the Linux machine where the core dump happened.But I am getting No symbol table info available for a particular thread number 1. For the remaining threads I am getting symbol table.

```
(gdb) t 1
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 0x7f799659f700 (LWP 12275))]#0  0x00007f799cead4b0 in __tls_get_addr () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x00007f799cead4b0 in __tls_get_addr () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007f799cead4b0 in __tls_get_addr () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f799c3d5ddc in __cxa_get_globals () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f799c3d6c56 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000000000413f57 in ExceptionHandler::SingleTonHandler::Handler ()
    at /fgw_dev/dev/source/BSG/include/bsg_exception.h:19
No locals.
#4  0x00007f799c3d6be6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007f799c3d6c13 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007f799c3d6c96 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x0000000000413f57 in ExceptionHandler::SingleTonHandler::Handler ()
    at /fgw_dev/dev/source/BSG/include/bsg_exception.h:19
No locals.
#8  0x00007f799c3d6be6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007f799c3d6c13 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
```

Based on the core bt it looks like some run time exception has resulted into the the program termination as the exception was not caught since throw was invoked without argument.Hence the program got terminated and core dumped.But we donot know the root cause that resulted into this exception.Please let me know how to debug this core file as it is not loading the symbols for this particular thread.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f799cead4b0 in __tls_get_addr () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x00007f799c3d5ddc in __cxa_get_globals () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007f799c3d6c56 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000000000413f57 in ExceptionHandler::SingleTonHandler::Handler ()
    at /fgw_dev/dev/source/BSG/include/bsg_exception.h:19
#4  0x00007f799c3d6be6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f799c3d6c13 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f799c3d6c96 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000000000413f57 in ExceptionHandler::SingleTonHandler::Handler ()
    at /fgw_dev/dev/source/BSG/include/bsg_exception.h:19
#8  0x00007f799c3d6be6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007f799c3d6c13 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007f799c3d6c96 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x0000000000413f57 in ExceptionHandler::SingleTonHandler::Handler ()
```

Thanks,

Comment: We don't know the root cause for this run time exception leading to program termination.Why it is throwing symbol not found only for this thread 1. Output of info threads:                * 1 Thread 0x7f799659f700 (LWP 12275)  0x00007f799cead4b0 in __tls_get_addr () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.Based on the kernel logs segmentation fault occured due to errno 6.                                        kernel: BSG.exe[12275]: segfault at 7f799649fff8 ip 00007f799cead4b0 sp 00007f79964a0000 error 6 in ld-2.12.so[7f799ce9c000+20000]

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting No symbol table

The "No symbol table" is a red herring; it has nothing to do with your problem.

> But we donot know the root cause that resulted into this exception

Did you show the *entire* output of the `backtrace` command?

It looks like you are arbitrarily truncating the output at 9 or 10 levels, and the output will go on "forever" if you let it.

If above guess is correct, you have a stack overflow, because your `SingleTonHandler::Handler` is constantly re-entering itself. You should also be able to find out the original exception by letting backtrace go long enough. Alternatively, `backtrace -20` should show you the outermost (oldest) 20 frames.